# Flutter: conflicting scrolls - PageView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have PageView inside NestedScrollView, but also I have a problem with this in some cases:

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1': ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.)
```

Also inside PageView I put another PageView for photo slider. How can I resolve it?

code:

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: _layout.theme.background,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      key: _homeNestedKey,
      ...
      body: PageView(
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        controller: _pageController,
        children: [
          RefresherWrapper(
            onRefresh: () => _onRefresh(_feedRefreshController),
            onLoading: () => _onLoading(_feedRefreshController),
            refreshController: _feedRefreshController,
            child: const FeedContent(),
          ),
          RefresherWrapper(
            onRefresh: () => _onRefresh(_promotionsRefreshController),
            onLoading: () => _onLoading(_promotionsRefreshController),
            refreshController: _promotionsRefreshController,
            child: const PromotionsContent(),
          ),
          RefresherWrapper(
            onRefresh: () => _onRefresh(_shopRefreshController),
            onLoading: () => _onLoading(_shopRefreshController),
            refreshController: _shopRefreshController,
            child: const ShopContent(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```